# How to encode Google API search queries?

Tags: javascript, google-api, urlencode

Searching Google Drive for files through their API, their docs ([here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)) say this about how to encode the search string:

> All examples on this page show the unencoded q parameter, where **name = 'hello'** is encoded as **name+%3d+%27hello%27**.

What is that? How do I encode the string like that?

`encodeURIComponent("name = 'hello'");` give me "name%3D'hello'"

Edit: I'm still very confused here. I'm trying now to just do a test query by hand and can't even get that to work. Based on the example above, this should work:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=name+%3d+%27hello%27&access_token=...
```

But even that, pasted out of their docs, gives me:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid query",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid query"
 }
}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

It works with the v3 of the Google Drive API and you don't have to use the + sign.

The following request based on the example you gave should work fine (with a valid access token of course) :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%3D%27hello%27&access_token=...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

> Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

var encoded = encodeURIComponent(str);

Example :

```
var q = "title contains 'hello'";
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q="+encodeURIComponent(q);
```

Comment: Tried that. `encodeURIComponent` doesn't make what they're looking for. See the example in my question.